# Some menu items of libreoffice only show a dash or are invisible

Tags: themes, libreoffice

I'm having the strangest problem, some menu items (if not most) of libreoffice are missing, they show a dash instead. Here's a picture of it:
[image: picture]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try changing some other theme. That `_` denotes hotkey for that menu

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I think your system misses the required `language pack` to show the correct word suitable to the language you have been used.Please run the `Language Support` application and install the one you need.Dont forget to click `Apply System wide` too.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 12.04 + XFCE4.10 (from ppa).
I also had this issue.
FIXED (sort off): The menu became visible when I disabled display compositing. (Main Menu -> Settings -> Settings Manager -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Compositor -> Enable display compositing.